# Rename existing backstage view control

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

I am trying to rename the backstage view control(File -> Info -> Protect Document -> restrict permission by people) for word 2010.

I thought of two solutions.

1. In XML if I can get the idmso control, I could change label or get label. But I am not able to do so as in XML I am not getting control inside group node.
2. If findcontrol method of C# could help me to find the back stage view like Other ribbon then I might set the label.

But all the above are not fruitfull for me.

even I don't know its possible or not. I am new to VSTO development so might my solution sound funny.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not able to do so as in XML I am not getting control inside group node.

What exactly do you need to do with the Backstage UI?

Note, it is not possible to override these commands from the custom UI XML markup or by using the object model. A possible solution would be to consider hiding the built-in UI and rebuilding it fully with custom commands.

You can read more about the Backstage UI in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx)